# How to add custom maven repository to gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have my maven repository with my aar file that is located there https://cloudbuild.myompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/com/myompany/myompany-core/2.0.0/

By the way it is private repository so when I'm logging in I should use credentials.

When I'm trying to add this to my dependencies gradle gives me error `Failed to resolve`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()


    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'admin'
            password '*******'
        }
        url 'https://cloudbuild.myompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ko.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile group: 'com.myompany', name: 'myompany-core', version: '2.0.0'
}
```

Also there is my POM file from 2.2.0 folder

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myompany-core</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<packaging>gradle</packaging>
<description>POM was created by Sonatype Nexus</description>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the actual http path of the pom file in the repo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'admin'
            password '*******'
        }
        url 'https://cloudbuild.livegenic.com/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}
```

See this discussion for more detail:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-username-password-only-works-when-embedded-in-url-for-some-servers/2542/13

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation addresses this here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:maven_repo

The official docs include both Groovy/Kotlin syntax and cover a range of options.