# Deploying Cloud Function with private dependencies

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-functions

this is my first question on SO I'll try my best to make it good.

My team deploys multiple Java Cloud Functions (GCP) using a few common classes (with maven to manage dependencies). Right now those classes are duplicated in each function and have to be updated everywhere at each code edit. Each Cloud Function is deployed from source.
To avoid duplicating those classes I packaged them in a jar, everything runs fine locally. I added this jar as a local dependency in each Cloud Function pom file and tried to deploy from jar by building a jar with all dependencies and providing it in the `--source` option of `gcloud deploy`. This causes a timeout error from what seems to be the jar uploading.

Error trace :

```
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storage.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: Caught socket error, retrying: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out',))
```

What I tried so far :

- Setting a higher deployment timeout with `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 10000` but this doesn't seem to apply to the uploading step as it fails always after a few minutes.
- Uploading my local dependency to a private nexus repository to deploy my functions from source as before, but the pull failed on a Wagon error when I run `mvn package` and I didn't find any solution either : `WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported transport protocol`

Detailed error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project get-content: Could not resolve dependencies for project project:cf:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at project:pipeline:jar:0.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for project:pipeline:jar:0.0.1: Could not transfer artifact project:pipeline:pom:0.0.1 from/to project-nexus (XXX): Cannot access XXX with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access XXX using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported transport protocol -> [Help 1]
```

I beleive this is only due to my jar with dependencies being to large for upload as I actually deployed the jar without dependency by mistake first (deploy succeded but class definition missing during execution). My question is how can I deploy my Cloud Function with one local/private dependency ?

Note :

- I can't upload my dependency to a public maven repository
- Each Cloud Function depends also on public maven dependencies which seems to be too large to package in a single jar for deployment

Comment: Did you have consider to use Artifact registry to store your Maven dependencies?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your suggestion ! I didn't know about this feature, I'll try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching from Maven to Gradle.
The problem was that Maven stores the repository authentification parameters in a local file `~/.m2/settings.xml` that Google Build can't access when building my Cloud Function for deployment.
I switched to Gradle to provide the authenfication in the `gradle.build` file directly following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282168/how-to-add-custom-maven-repository-to-gradle).